# Ubuntu 14.04 does not detect my WiFi SSID

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Acer laptop alongside Windows 7.

Recently, I had to switch my modem/router, after it stopped working. I contacted my ISP's Tech Support and they send me a new device. So, I tried connecting to my WiFi with the new router, but its SSID is not on the list of the available networks. Windows 7 and other devices (Phone/Tablet) are able to find it and connect just fine. I am still able to connect with an ethernet cable.

I am relatively new to Ubuntu and after searching online for similar issues, I could not find a solution. Is this a driver issue? Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: On which channel is it transmitting?

Comment: It is set on Auto (Current channel: 13).

Comment: As I thought. Switch to a lower channel. Since channels above 11 are illegal in some countries, not all the drivers support them.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! Will this change interfere in any way, with the connections of the other devices?

Comment: No, there will be no problems on other devices. i write a answer, then please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to a lower channel. Since channels above 11 are illegal in some countries, not all the drivers support them.